# Запись в лог

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня тут проблема возникла в очередной раз, не могу записать в переменную ошибки которые выдает мне программа по мере её выполнения, из за того что переменную не видно из внутренних функций, из кода по комментариям понятно где начинаются проблемы:

```
   var log;
//читаем json строку предоставленную в файле
function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //открываем файл для чтения и видим что там строка
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        $.each(response.file, function(file_idx, files) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 //пока еще видно то что пишем в log
                 //записываем в файл что-то
                 function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                      writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                          //..
                      };
                      //
                      // log видно по сюда, дальше нет
                      //
                      //посылаем введенные данные с формы
                      $.post(postTo, { who: files.name, pass: $('[name=pass]').val() },
                                             //лог не записывается уже
                                             //обрабатываем пришедшие данные
                         function(data) {
                                                    //log не записывается
                            //если данные не пустые то обрабатываем их
                            if(data != "") {
                                //и дальше не видно то что я записываю в эту переменную...
//.. куча кода ...
                            } else {
                                console.log("Could not connect to server");
                        }
                     });

                     //пишем что то в файл

                      console.log(log);
                     writer.write("pure foo");
                     writer.abort();
                     }
                 return false;
                 });
            });
        });
    }; reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Знаю что надоел с глупыми вопросами, но сам я не могу придумать как это решить, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: >Выучите матчасть, прочтите пару книг, **попишите немного академического кода**. Или вы до старости будете на hashcode писать по любому вопросу связанному с javascript?

© @AlexWindHope

Comment: не катит, матчасть давно пройдена и прочтена, в моем случае нужна помощь сторонних лиц

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо почитать мат-часть по поводу замыканий в javascript'e, например [здесь](http://javascript.ru/basic/closure).

Решением в Вашем случае будет сделать log = ""; вместо var log;

Comment: пробовал, пишет что переменная не определена

Comment: Ну, а скажем, window.log = "" и далее через window.log юзать?

Comment: так же не работает.
\

Comment: может кто-то трёт? попробуйте лог тогда замкнуть в функцию?